# place a multi-line output inside a variable

Tags: bash, bash4

I'm writing a script in bash and I want it to execute a command and to handle each line separately. for example:

```
LINES=$(df)
echo $LINES
```

it will return all the output converting new lines with spaces.

example:

if the output was supposed to be:

```
1
2
3
```

then I would get

```
1 2 3
```

how can I place the output of a command into a variable allowing new lines to still be new lines so when I print the variable i will get proper output?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generally in bash `$v` is asking for trouble in most cases. Almost always what you really mean is `"$v"` in **double quotes**:

```sh
LINES="$(df)"
echo "$LINES"
```

Comment: Actually neither assignment to variable needs quotes, because result of expansion is not word-split when assigning to variable. But they don't hurt anything and it's easier to train your muscle-memory to just type double quotes around all expansions.

Answer (score 7):

No, it will not. The `$(something)` only strips trailing newlines.

The expansion in argument to echo splits on whitespace and than echo concatenates separate arguments with space. To preserve the whitespace, you need to quote again:

```
echo "$LINES"
```

Note, that the assignment does *not* need to be quoted; result of expansion is not word-split in assignment to variable and in argument to `case`. But it can be quoted and it's easier to just learn to just always put the quotes in.

Comment: Are you sure?   I got the expected results just with `LINES=$(df); echo "${LINES}"`,  perhaps IFS is different in our environment.  Still +1 as `$(df)` is better than single backtick quotes in @kubanczyk's answer

Comment: @nhed: Right... assignment to variable never splits. I got confused by error message that turned out to be coming from something else when I tested it here.

Comment: @nhed: `$()` is preferred over ``, because it's easier to see and because it is easier to nest.

Comment: @kubanczyk back-ticks is old school, first it is not easy on the eyes (back-ticks within double quotes), second it limits what you can do.  Embedding 2 commands, For example: `echo $$ > /tmp/mypid; LINES=$(ps $(cat /tmp/mypid)); echo "${LINES}"` works ...  the same with backticks won't